# How to change switch color if it is disabled?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, less

I have to change color of ActivitySwitch if it is disable. Whenever checkbox is uncheked, change switch color to **grey**. I am using MUI to create component.
Here is my code :

```
 <ActivitySwitch
              name={"ampm"}
              defaultValue={true}
              disabled={!isChecked}
              value={!isNetFlowIsChecked ? "AM" : "PM"}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleChange}
              activeToggleText="AM"
              inactiveToggleText="PM"
            />
    
CSS : 

switch: {
    "& span.MuiSwitch-root": {
      height: "15px !important",
      width: 30,
      padding: 0,
      marginTop: 4,
      "& span.MuiButtonBase-root": {
        height: "12px !important",
        padding: "0 3px",
      },
      "& span.MuiSwitch-thumb": {
        width: 9,
        height: 9,
      },
      "& span.MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked": {
        transform: "translateX(13px)",
      },
    },
```